# Django-nose test case gives assertion error when run from management command

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, nose

test.py

```
# write code to test the views.
from django.test import Client

# import nose for tests.
import nose.tools as noz

class TestSettings(object):
    """ test the nose test related setup """

    def setup(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def testTestUser(self):
        """ Tests if the django user 'test' is setup properly."""
        # login the test user
        response = self.client.login(username=u'test', password=u'test')    
        noz.assert_equal(response, True)
```

when this code is run from management command, gives the following output :

```
    $ ./manage.py test <app-name>
    nosetests --verbosity 1 <app-name>
    Creating test database for alias 'default'...
    F
    ======================================================================
    FAIL: Tests if the django user 'test' is setup properly.
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "/<python-sitepackages-dir-path>/nose/case.py",                                                                                       line 197, in runTest
       self.test(*self.arg)
       File "<application-path>/tests.py", line 28, in testTestUser
       noz.assert_equal(response, True)
    AssertionError: False != True

    ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    Ran 1 test in 0.008s

    FAILED (failures=1)
    Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

now the same commands when run thrugh the django shell gives the following:

```
    $ ./manage.py shell
    Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 11 2012, 08:28:27) 
    [GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    (InteractiveConsole)
    >>> from django.test import Client
    >>> 
    >>> import nose.tools as noz
    >>> 
    >>> client = Client()
    >>> response = client.login(username=u'test', password=u'test')
    >>> noz.assert_equal(response, True)
    >>> 
    >>> 
    >>> response
    True
    >>>
```

The user 'test' is active in django for the current scenrio.

Why am i getting this error assertion while i run the management command ?

Comment: folks figured it out see:

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16116776/django-user-setup-for-nose-tests/16116959#16116959>

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's not inheriting the base test class, so it's not calling the setup method prior to your test. I would recommend inheriting from Django's TestCase class, as per [the Django documentation on testing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/testing/overview/). In this case, it would look like this:

```
# write code to test the views.
from django.test import Client
import unittest

# import nose for tests.
import nose.tools as noz

class TestSettings(unittest.TestCase):
    """ test the nose test related setup """

    def setUp(self):  # Note that the unittest requires this to be setUp and not setup
        self.client = Client()

    def testTestUser(self):
        """ Tests if the django user 'test' is setup properly."""
        # login the test user
        response = self.client.login(username=u'test', password=u'test')    
        noz.assert_equal(response, True)
```

Comment: @d03514 can u both try runing the test as per your solutions and share the output

Comment: I would imagine it would be easier for you to run, I do not have a user named test set up in my local db.

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating a user with username `test` and password `test` for your tests? Or loading fixtures? I bet not.

When you are using the shell you are logging in against the database in your settings.py. When you are in a test you are using your test database, which is empty at the beginning of every test, so there are no users.

In `setUp` you could create a user

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
User.objects.create('test', 'test@test.com', 'test')
```

As @Kevin London pointed out too

your setup command should be

`setUp`, but I don't think that has much to do with it since each `TestCase` has a `client` by default.

Comment: So how to by default load a test user .. that is the actual intention for testing all views that have user.is_authenticated()

Comment: @cool_n_curious I usually create a test user in the setUp method that way you can log in that user in whatever views you need to test against an authenticated user

Comment: doesnot work ! tried before i asked .. 

here is what i did ..

in global scope:
    `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

modified setup:
    `def setup(self):`
        `#noz.set_trace()`
        `self.client = Client()`
        `# setup a test user`
        `usr = User(username='test', password='test')`
        `usr.save()`