# Django user setup for nose tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, nose

I tried seting up a user for nose tests but it doesnot work

in global scope defined:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import nose.tools as noz
```

inside a test class defined:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.client = Client()
    user = User(username="test", password="test")
    user.save()
```

The user is saved, which i have tested with the noz.set_trace()
but when a test function calls for the same user's login, assertion error is raised:

```
nosetests --verbosity 1
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
> <app-path>/tests.py(59)testTestUser()
-> response = self.client.login(username=u'test', password=u'test')
(Pdb) User.objects.all()
[<User: test>]
```

the testTestUser function is defined like:

```
def testTestUser(self):
    """ Tests if the django user 'test' is setup properly."""
    noz.set_trace()
    # login the test user
    response = self.client.login(username='test', password='test')    
    noz.assert_equal(response, True)
```

relevant test output is :

```
    noz.assert_equal(response, True)
       AssertionError: False != True

    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Ran 1 test in 0.011s

    FAILED (failures=1)
```

My intention is to test views that have requst.user.is_authenicated() branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out from : 
http://www.pukkared.com/2011/07/simulating-user-login-in-a-django-view-unit-test/

the proper code is:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.client = Client()
    user = User.objects.create_user(username="test", password="test")

def testTestUser(self):
    """ Tests if the django user 'test' is setup properly."""
    noz.set_trace()
    # login the test user
    response = self.client.login(username='test', password='test')    
    noz.assert_equal(response, True)
```